# Weak simulation of Clifford circuits

Tags: reference-request, quantum-computing

Quantum circuits composed by Clifford gates can be simulated by classical computation in polynomial time. More precisely, this simulation should be a weak simulation, i.e. it is possible to sample the outcome of measurements of the output state of the circuit. This is stated, e.g., [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.0898)

An explicit method for sampling the outcome of the measurement is given in [the above mentioned paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.0898) and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0504117). In both cases, the used formalism is different from the most traditional one, based on normalizer groups and stabilizers.

This latter formalism was used in [the seminal paper of Gottesman (with Knill in references.)](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9807006v1). Very roughly, the original idea was to use the Heisenberg representation. Instead of having a vector $\left|\Psi\right>$ that evolves like $O\left|\Psi\right>$, there is an operator $N$ evolving as $O^{\dagger}NO$. When $N$ is chosen in the Pauli group, and $O$ is the evolution generated by a quantum circuit made of Clifford gates, then $O^{\dagger}NO$ remains in the Pauli group. The representation of $N$ and its evolution under the Clifford gates can be done quickly by classical calculation.

It is thus possible to efficiently compute the expectation values $\left<\Psi\right|O^{\dagger}NO\left|\Psi\right>$, but this should be a task for strong simulation.

To deal with states, it is noticed that a state $\left|\Psi\right>$ is uniquely defined by giving $n$ operators $N_n$ (belonging to the Pauli group), such that $N_n\left|\Psi\right>=\left|\Psi\right>$. If we want to use the Gottesman formalism for weak simulation, it should be possible to classically sample the outcome of the measurements of single qubits of the state $\left|\Psi\right>$, given the operators $N_n$. However, I do not see a proof of this. Is this true? If so, do you have references?